# Sudo command not working in Jenkins Console

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, sudo, jenkins-cli

Sudo command is not working from Jenkins Console while executing shell command.
It is still showing user as jenkins, Kindly suggest

```
+ whoami
jenkins
+ hostname
ip-123-23-34-23
+ sudo su - admin
+ whoami
jenkins
```

**Updated:**

How can I execute other commands if my user is admin like export and python command. It is saying python command not found, but if I switch shell to **Bash**, python command will get execute

```
+ echo /tmp/jenkins4181446190720754051.sh
/tmp/jenkins4181446190720754051.sh
+ bash
+ sudo su - admin -c whoami
admin
+ bash
+ echo /tmp/jenkins4181446190720754051.sh
/tmp/jenkins4181446190720754051.sh
+ whoami
jenkins
+ export ADMIN_HOME=/home/admin
+ python /home/admin/scripts/bin/script.py STG
/tmp/jenkins4181446190720754051.sh: 11: python: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Kindly suggest

Do not use `su` in a non-interactive session, as spawning a login shell without any input is pointless. Instead use the command non-interactively.

```
sudo -u jenkins whoami
sudo su - admin -c 'whoami'
```

Comment: Can you please check my updated query. It says python not exist. By default It is taking other shell, not bash shell and I don't know if python script is going to execute with admin user or jenkins user